# What is difference between jenkins & Urban code build

Tags: jenkins

Can someone please share your experience on difference that u felt as difference between jenkins & UCbuild

P.S: Please post some technical aspects.

Comment: Jenkins is free, you can start using now. You can get commercial support from CloudBees(original developer is with them) , if you need training and production quality support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins - CI tool
UBuild - only used for Build.

Deployment can be automated with Jenkins whereas it is not advisable with UBuild

Answer (score 0):

Continuous integration can be defined in many ways, but it is started with source code build integration for every commit on VCS system. The same was extended to perform deployments into servers which is typically handled by deployment automation tools like urban code etc...
Both the Jenkins and Urban code together can make Continuous Integration + Continuous Delivery.

Even we can make use of Jenkins for deployments using plugins, but it will not support complex server environments with rollbacks and patch deployments etc.
Depending on your deployment environment/ servers architecture you can choose any of devops tool ( Urban code, RunDeck, JRebel and BladeLogic etc).

Comment: JRebel isn't a devops tool. It's the tool for _developers_.